# Putting delay until next page is loaded fully in Selenium IDE

Tags: user-interface, selenium, web, selenium-ide, web-testing

I am trying to automate a test case using selenium IDE. I have installed this add-on on firefox. I am trying to login using admin/admin credentials in one of the websites and after that it takes couple of seconds to load the next page fully.

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=username</td>
    <td>admin</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=password</td>
    <td>admin</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=button.btn</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>30000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=span.ncs-tree-nav</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

`waitForPageToLoad` is not working, ideally it should wait for 30 seconds but as soon as login button gets clicked, test case throws error as it is not able to find next element on the page.

Here is the output from IDE :-

```
[info] Executing: |open | /login.html | |
[info] Executing: |type | id=username | admin |
[info] Executing: |type | id=password | admin |
[info] Executing: |click | css=button.btn | |
[info] Executing: |waitForPageToLoad | 30000 | |
[info] Executing: |click | css=span.ncs-tree-nav | |
[error] Element css=span.ncs-tree-nav not found
```

As soon as login is done, it moved for searching expected navigation and error came.
It will be helpful if someone can point out if I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pragmatic approach,

If you have some visual condition that gets true just when the page is loaded, you can look for that.
Say that the text "Welcome User" gets displayed in a span with id=content somewhere when the page is loaded, you can replace your waitForPageToLoad with

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>waitForText</td>
>   <td>id=content</td>
>   <td>Welcome*</td>
> </tr>
> ```

Possibly you can even be as blunt as

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>waitForText</td>
>   <td>//body</td>
>   <td>*Welcome*</td>
> </tr>
> ```

though I haven't tested the latter myself.

Comment: Thanks for this alternate solution. I tried putting `pause` and it solved the issue! Will try your solution, too!

Comment: `[error] Timed out after 30000ms` got this error with `waitForText`

Comment: Hm. I use the waitForText in several of my test cases and it works for me. Hard to say what is wrong if not seeing the html. Did you notice my usage of the asterix '*' (a wildcard)?

Comment: I have put exact text which is going to appear on that page. After that timeout error, it could find the element.

Comment: Ok. Maybe the second of my suggestions is more straight-forward to use, if you care to give it another try. I have tested it myself now and it works fine for me. You will have less risk of running into problems with it if you pick a small portion of plain text (not from a button or other complex control) and replace the Welcome in my example with your small portion of text. Take care to use the asterixes before and after. But on the other hand, since you already found a solution with a `pause` maybe you are good with that.

Answer (score 1):

If your page reloads after clicking, you have to use **clickAndWait** instead of **click**:

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=button.btn</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=span.ncs-tree-nav</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

If the page does not reload, upper code won't work. In this case wait for a presence of an element that you are going to use on the next step:

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=button.btn</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=span.ncs-tree-nav</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=span.ncs-tree-nav</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```